# Object [object Object] has no method with Rails and jQuery asset pipeline

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I'm getting an error with one of my jQuery function:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'timepicker'
```

I have `jquery.timepicker.js` in **vendor/assets/javascripts**, using this [library](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/)

In my **app/assets/javascripts/application.js** I have this

```
//= require jquery.timepicker
```

which brings in the jquery file. I can even see it being loaded in my inspection element using chrome browser.

In my other file where I'm writing the function, I have this

```
jQuery ->
  $(".time_avail").timepicker ->
```

which gives me this in the browser:

```
(function() {
  jQuery(function() {
    return $(".time_avail").timepicker(function() {});
  });

}).call(this);
```

My view file does have the input field with class

```
<input class="time_avail time-picker" id="hour_open_time" name="hour[open_time]" size="30" type="text" />
```

What am I doing wrong to deserve this error?

Comment: check the browser developer tools network tab to see whether the timepicker library is downloaded/included

Comment: try to console $.fn.datepicker() in Firebug. Hope you can got the function

Comment: @ArunPJohny I checked in the network tab and it shows up in the list.

Comment: @F1beta I checked firebug and type in what you said in the console and got this `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'`

Comment: if the error says datepicker, then you are missing the jquery-ui library

Comment: One more check. do you load jQuery again after the plugin load. If you load plugin and jquery after the plugin then I am sure their are some kind of error have shown in Firebug.

Comment: @andrewliu In the file (minfied or dev of UI in .js) search for it. I thing it have been missing.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I realized that it isn't `datepicker` that i"m using, it is `timepicker`, which I downloaded the script from the library link in my post.

Comment: @F1beta I'm not sure what you mean, I check `inspect element` in chrome and under `elements` tab, I can see the list of files that are loaded, jquery.js, jquery.ujs, then jquery.timepicker.js, then application.js is loaded at the end.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I do however have jquery.ui.datepicker downloaded with my site... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had a conflict on my jquery,

In one of my coffeescript files, I had something like this going...

```
jQuery ->
  #more code
  $(".time_avail").timepicker ->
```

but when I changed it to this:

jQuery ->
  #more code

```
$.noConflic()
  jQuery(document).ready ($) ->
  $(".time_avail").timepicker ->
```

It works... not sure if this is the correct way, but I'm finally able to see the times when clicking on an input field

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I wanted to add a new method to jQuery, and used the following (lifted from andrewliu's own answer):

application.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
  $.noConflict() ->
    $.fn.isOnScreen = ->
      win = $(window)
      viewport =
        top: win.scrollTop()
        left: win.scrollLeft()

      viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width()
      viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height()
      bounds = @offset()
      bounds.right = bounds.left + @outerWidth()
      bounds.bottom = bounds.top + @outerHeight()
      not (viewport.right < bounds.left or viewport.left > bounds.right or viewport.bottom < bounds.top or viewport.top > bounds.bottom)
```

So, basically the key is to wrap your extra jQuery methods inside the `noConflict()`. Although, I have no idea why this is necessary. Maybe someone else can explain.